# Qual è il significato di "ariate" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Osservavo Emilia Pio svelta nel ribattere a grandi **ariate**, critica per abitudine e per attitudine curiosa; e Margherita Cantelma, marchesa di Cotrone con la piccola testa dai ricci spiritosi e un'allegria devota sempre dedicata a me.

L'io narrante di questa frase è Isabella d'Este, marchesa di Mantova, figlia di Ercole I d'Este ed Eleonora d'Aragona. Non capisco il senso di "ariate" nel testo. Ho cercato i vocaboli "ariata" e "ariato", ma non li ho trovati in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Potreste spiegarmene il significato?

**Aggiornamento:** 
Adesso mi sono accorta che, alla fine del libro, l'autrice usa di nuovo il termine "ariate" in questa frase:

> Me lo ripeto per esserne sicura mentre aspiro le intermittenti **ariate** lacustri.

Qui ha chiaramente il significato di "aria",  cioè,  il vapor d'acqua che si sprigiona dalla superficie lacustre.

Comment: Potrebbe essere forse un'invenzione della Bellonci facendo riferimento all'“aria” in senso musicale (cioè il modo di ribattere di Emilia ricorda le arie d'opera)? Un po' tirata per il capelli...

Comment: @DaG: Ummm... E nel Rinascimento l'opera non si era ancora inventata.

Comment: No, ma la Bellonci non viveva nel rinascimento! :-) Possibile anacronismo? E comunque avevo detto che era un'idea tirata per i capelli. (Mi rendo conto  inoltre che non so da quando si usa “aria” in senso musicale: buona idea per una domanda.)

Comment: @DaG: Mi sembra poco probabile perché il testo è scritto in prima persona e l'io narrante è Isabella d'Este. L'azione di questa frase accade nel 1502, subito dopo le nozze di Alfonso I d'Este (il fratello di Isabella) con Lucrezia Borgia. E in genere la Bellonci sembra molto ben documentata...

Comment: Per caso Emilia Pio è un personaggio negativo? Se lo è,  magari l'espressione è imparentata con *dare aria alla bocca*.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: Non è un personaggio negativo: si tratta di un nobildonna amica di Isabella d'Este e di sua cognata Elisabetta Gonzaga (si tratta di un [personaggio storico](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/elisabetta-gonzaga-duchessa-di-urbino_(Dizionario-Biografico)/)).

Comment: Noto ora che “ariata” è usato soprattutto nell'italiano di Sicilia per “aria”, detto dell'aspetto di una persona: “giovanotto dall'ariata semplice e comune”, “un'ariata di compatimento”. Lo usa molto Camilleri: vedi [qui](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/arbulo.htm). Che si riferisca al fatto che Emilia Pio si dà molte arie (di intenditrice, per esempio?) Ma qui l'area geografica sembra tutt'altra...

Comment: Potrebbe indicare l'utilizzo dell'ariete quindi il ribadire con forza e con ritmo incalzante tipico dell'arma medioevale.

Comment: Avevo l'impressione che fosse un uso toscano. Un amico mi ha confermato che "ariata" ha il significato di "fiammata", "vampata", "vampa", ma purtroppo non riusciamo a trovare una fonte. Nel brano starebbe a indicare un modo di parlare focoso, intenso.